# Smallest distance from set of location co-ordinates from current location on MAP

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a set of location co-ordinates as LatLang objects.I want to find distance between which  LatLang from set to current location is smallest ?How can i find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to calculate distance between all your points and Current point and check the smallest distance manually. Like compare current point X with points A, B, C and D. And save the smallest distance in a variable
this is in Javascript just convert it in Java code its easy

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {

  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

And to calculate radians to degree to this

radians=(degrees*pi)/180

Comment: Does this give smallest driving distance or physical?I want driving distance.

Comment: @Mario This will give you crow flight distance i.e. flat distance between these geographical points.!!

Comment: how can i get traveling distance?

Comment: I think there is an API that Google provides that will help you calculate road distance. Some "Google distance API"
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/
Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

As per my way

```
final ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Now, implement for loop like: add all the Markers in Map and find distance between Current Position and Marker position and add into `Integer arrayList`

```
for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {


            all = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.mark_red))
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitudes.get(i)
                                    .toString()), Double
                                    .parseDouble(longitudes.get(i)
                                            .toString())))
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(city.get(i)));


            float[] results = new float[1];
            Location.distanceBetween(
                    Double.parseDouble(latitudes.get(i).toString()),
                    Double.parseDouble(longitudes.get(i).toString()),
                    cur_pos.latitude, cur_pos.longitude, results);
            System.out.println("Distance is: " + results[0]);

            arrayList.add((int) results[0]);

        }
```

Now, find the Min value `minIndex` from arrayList that is **Min Distance index**

```
int minIndex = arrayList.indexOf(Collections.min(arrayList));
```

At the last add `Min Distance` Marker like

```
Currnt = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.mark_red))
                .position(
                        new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitudes
                                .get(minIndex).toString()), Double
                                .parseDouble(longitudes.get(
                                        minIndex).toString())))
                .title(locations.get(minIndex))
                .snippet(city.get(minIndex)));
```

Comment: Does this give smallest driving distance or physical?I want driving distance.

Comment: @Mario it'll give you `Physical distance`. if you want driving distance then you probably go with `Direction API`.